# Removing double quotes from json response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I use basic array to make reference to icons like this:

```
{name: "text", avatar: srcs[15]}
```

This works great, but now I dynamically create an array from my json api and it gives me array of objects like this:

```
{name: "text", avatar: "srcs[15]"}
```

so I cannot reference to my avatars now. How can I remove double quotes to get my array work again?

Please note that I don't want to get the `srcs[15]` value to the array, just make a reference to the source array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is self-contained static data, and it can't reference named variables or objects outside of its own structure.

You can do it like this instead:

```
{ "name": "text", "avatarIndex": 15 }
```

And then do one of these to use it:

```
var avatar = srcs[data.avatarIndex];  // Avatar object in separate variable
// or
data.avatar = srcs[data.avatarIndex]; // Avatar object added into data
```

Comment: this could be a good and easy solution, the only problem is that avatar variable makes the reference at this moment and I cannot append it to my object

Comment: thank you for help, but I don't think it will work. `data.avatar = srcs[data.avatarIndex];` will put srcs data inside my array, while I just want to make reference to it

Comment: I made some changes in code, following your advice to get the `avatarIndex` and it finally works

Answer (score 4):

The JSON data format does not support references. What you want it not possible.

You need to either:

- Put the data you want there explicitly (this may involve duplication) *or*
- Describe the relationship in a way that the program consuming the JSON can interpret as a reference. You could use [the `reviver` argument of `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to inflate the description back to the data you want to point it to.

Comment: thanks for this advice, I'll see how I can make this work

Answer (score 0):

You should just put either the value or the whole array , you have also to read about what format json support [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)

Here's my suggested solutions

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]



var json1 = {
  name: 'test',
  value: array
}

console.log("solution 1 :" + json1.value[2])

var json2 = {
  name: 'test',
  value: array[2]
}

console.log("solution 2 :" + json2.value)
```